# unable to access or navigate the image file in jsp code

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am unable to navigate to image file in my `jsp` code. Both .jsp and image files are in different directories. I want to use image in my `header.jsp` file. Below is the snapshot. Guide me.

[image]

As you can see, my `header.jsp` file is under `WebContent > WEB-ING > views` folder. I am unable to load the image in this jsp. Also, as it is seen `pic.png` file is under `resources > images`. How can I load that image in my `Header.jsp` using `<img src="">` tag. Guide me.

Comment: Place the image somewhere in `WEB-INF` not in `resources` - the same should apply to CSS etc.

Comment: are you using spring?

Comment: @OlehKurpiak yes, exactly.

Comment: @OlehKurpiak and I am new it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use spring you should specify the directory with resources

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

you project should look like this

```
rootDir
   - src(java sources)
   - resources(images, css, js etc.)
   - webapp(here is web-inf, meta-inf etc.)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using eclipse. so try using this path:

/YOUR PROJECT NAME/resources/images/pic.png